# Getting local frame given a rotated base frame

Tags: math, rotational-matrices

I am working on the inverse kinematics of my 6 DOF robot arm. It works by specifying a position and the orientation. The orientation is given as a 3 dimensional matrix in world frame. Given this orientation, I need to transfer it to my end effector frame (local frame). At rest, the projection of the end effector frame to the world frame ***P6_0*** is:

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | -1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |

When i give an orientation in world frame, I want to find the corresponding orientation in local frame. The way I have tried to do this is by taking world frame orientation and multiplying with the inverse of ***P6_0***. This ends up being wrong in most cases, but it works for some rotations too?

Comment: In order to transform matrix to another matrix you need to transform each basis vector of the transformed matrix separately instead of multiplying it as whole matrix. Your question lacks details and MCVE along with sample in/out so do not expect any valid answers other than simple guess/suggestion comments like this...

Comment: robotics IK is a relatively well-published subject, [what did you (re)search yourself already](/help/how-to-ask) before you decided to post here? Because a websearch for "6DOF IK matrix" shows me a lot of high quality content that goes into excruciating detail, with code, on how to do this.